# MongoDB update all document using JavaScript

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have collection with following data.

```
{
     _id: ObjectID(....),
     ...
     data : [ 23, 34]
}
```

I have following JavaScript function.

```
function reduce(array){
    //some computation
    return result; // not array
}
```

Is there any way to update all the collection using MongoDB shell with following net effect.

```
{
    data : reduce(data)
}
```

Edit:

I am looking to execute this for only one time as part of migration.

Comment: You can make use of stored functions: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/

Comment: I am looking to execute this for only one time as part of migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could iterate over [MongoDB cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/) using [`cursor.forEach()` method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/) and saving processed documents with [`db.collection.save()` method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/), e.g.:

```js
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.data = reduce(doc.data); // update field
  db.collection.save(doc); // save
})
```